# jquery show and hide not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created a menu using jquery. when I click on the menu link, all the menus are opened. I have tried using show and hide class and after using,now nothing is working. The behavior should be when I click on the first link, rest other should be closed. Can some body please help me to troubleshoot this issue. I don't know where I'm getting it wrong. I'm not even getting console errors in browser

My Code below

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
      $(".image-container").click(function () {
        $(".dropup").slideToggle().delay(2000);
      });
    });
```

```css
   .application-container{
    position: relative;
  }
/* The dropup container */
.dropup{
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: initial;
  display: none;
}

/* Dropup content (hidden by default) */
.dropup-content {
  
  width:100%;
  bottom:-100%;
  left:0%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container application-container">
    <div class="row seven-rows">
      <div class="column text-center image-container">
        <img src="./images/aoe_icons_services_order_management.png" width='69' height='61' alt="e-commerce">
        <p class="mt-2 text-custom">E Commerce</p>
      </div>
      <div class="dropup show">
        <div class="dropup-content pt-4 pb-4">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 ml-5">
              <h3> Innovative Omnichannel E-Commerce Solutions</h3>
              <p>AOE develops flexible and high-performance Enterprise E-Commerce portals. Our solutions digitize business
                processes and create efficient, profitable platforms for providers and customers.</p>
              <a class="btn btn-custom">E Commerce Solutions</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column text-center image-container">
        <img src="./images/aoe_icons_webportal.png" width='69' height='61' alt="web portals">
        <p class="mt-2 text-custom">Web Portals</p>
      </div>
      <div class="dropup show">
        <div class="dropup-content">
          <div class="header">
            <h2>Mega Menu</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
              <h3>Category 1</h3>
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
              <h3>Category 2</h3>
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Can you explain properly step by step what you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to create a menu. On click of it, the menu should open and if I click again, it should close. But, for me, all the menus are opening at the same time. I want, only which I click should open and rest should be closed @ThanveerShah

Comment: I dont understand , I only see one Mega Menu.There is no other menu apart from this

Comment: It's behind the mega menu.........all the stacked on top of another. In the html there are two dropupmenus@ThanveerShah

Comment: Okay i understood. I'll post the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have modified your code, Check and tell me if this is want you wanted.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#section-1").click(function() {
    $("#drop-1").slideToggle();
  });
  $("#section-2").click(function() {
    $("#drop-2").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.application-container {
  position: relative;
}


/* The dropup container */
.dropup {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: initial;
  display: none;
}


/* Dropup content (hidden by default) */
.dropup-content {
  width: 100%;
  bottom: -100%;
  left: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container application-container">
    <div class="row seven-rows">
      <div class="column text-center image-container" style="background-color: red" id="section-1">
        <img src="./images/aoe_icons_services_order_management.png" width='69' height='61' alt="e-commerce">
        <p class="mt-2 text-custom">E Commerce</p>
      </div>
      <div class="dropup show" id="drop-1">
        <div class="dropup-content pt-4 pb-4">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 ml-5">
              <h3> Innovative Omnichannel E-Commerce Solutions</h3>
              <p>AOE develops flexible and high-performance Enterprise E-Commerce portals. Our solutions digitize business processes and create efficient, profitable platforms for providers and customers.</p>
              <a class="btn btn-custom">E Commerce Solutions</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column text-center image-container" id="section-2">
        <img src="./images/aoe_icons_webportal.png" width='69' height='61' alt="web portals">
        <p class="mt-2 text-custom">Web Portals</p>
      </div>
      <div class="dropup show" id="drop-2">
        <div class="dropup-content">
          <div class="header">
            <h2>Mega Menu</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
              <h3>Category 1</h3>
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
              <h3>Category 2</h3>
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: No problem , If you could accept my answer by clicking on the "tick" that could help me out :)

Answer (score 1):

If yow want the first item to be visible at page load, add the class *show* to the first dropup : `<div class="dropup show">`. If you want both dropups invisible unless `<image-container>` is clicked do: `<div class="dropup">`:

I hope I understood your needs well and this is what you need:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
      $(".image-container").on('click', function () {
        var delayTime = 250;
        var $dropup = $(this).next(".dropup");
        if($dropup.is(':visible')){
          $dropup.delay(delayTime).slideUp(200);
        } else {
          $dropup.delay(delayTime).slideDown(200);
        }
        $(".dropup").hide();
      });
    });
```

```css
.application-container{
    position: relative;
  }
/* The dropup container */
.dropup{
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: initial;
  display: none;
}

.dropup.show {
  display: block;
}

/* Dropup content (hidden by default) */
.dropup-content {
  
  width:100%;
  bottom:-100%;
  left:0%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container application-container">
    <div class="row seven-rows">
      <div class="column text-center image-container">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/69/61/" width='69' height='61' alt="e-commerce">
        <p class="mt-2 text-custom">E Commerce</p>
      </div>
      <div class="dropup show">
        <div class="dropup-content pt-4 pb-4">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 ml-5">
              <h3> Innovative Omnichannel E-Commerce Solutions</h3>
              <p>AOE develops flexible and high-performance Enterprise E-Commerce portals. Our solutions digitize business
                processes and create efficient, profitable platforms for providers and customers.</p>
              <a class="btn btn-custom">E Commerce Solutions</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column text-center image-container">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/69/61/" width='69' height='61' alt="web portals">
        <p class="mt-2 text-custom">Web Portals</p>
      </div>
      <div class="dropup">
        <div class="dropup-content">
          <div class="header">
            <h2>Mega Menu</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
              <h3>Category 1</h3>
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
              <h3>Category 2</h3>
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Its's working. But there seems to be a little problem. First time I click, the menu it opens, second time when I click, it should close right. But, its not closing, it's reopening the itself. Can you help me a little

Comment: Yes it's better now. Thank You for your help

Comment: @ShaswatiBhattacharyya It will work regardless of the number of menu items.